# Align subsequent ternary operators in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there a way in PhpStorm to align subsequent ternary operators so that the `?` (question marks) and the `:` (colons) are under each other?

Expected output:

```
$foo = empty($var)         ? 'default_value'     : $var;
$bar = empty($another_var) ? 'default_value_two' : $another_var;
```

The only option I see in `File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->PHP->Wrapping and Braces` that is related to *ternary operators* (by the end) is about single line -and wrapping it- and not about having multiple aligned in relation to each other.

---

To give a bit of perspective, the option that's called `Alignment statement->Align consecutive assignments (if checked)` produces this result:

```
$foo          = 'some value';
$another_name = 'another_value';
```

So, is there a way to make PhpStorm align the ternary operators in such manner?

*I'm using PhpStorm 2017.2.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible .. and at the moment is not even planned for any specific version (based on "Backlog" status of the corresponding ticket).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17880 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: That's sad, but I guess I was already expecting such answer :\

Comment: @FirstOne I wont delete this comment anytime soon : the list of long-standing *customer* requests with a large number of upvotes is rather large at Jetbrains.

Comment: That particular ticket has **0 (zero)** votes (excluding original author) .. which shows very little interest from other users. If it would be a "much needed" feature .. then you would see duplicate tickets (e.g. created by another user that could not find existing ticket at that time) or simply more votes. At the same time YvesLeBorg is also right -- there are quite a lot of tickets with high number of votes that are not getting implemented for whatever reason (lets exclude hard to reproduce bugs or those that may be affected by specific OS/JDK)...